# SEO urls with kohana strategy

Tags: php, url, seo, kohana

I want to use SEO urls in kohana, I already use htaccess file so I can have www.food.com/food/3123

Id:3123
title:hotdog

but thats not SEO friendly ,how would I get it to www.food.com/food/hotdog ? or www.food.com/food/I-love-hotdog ?

Searching DB with hotdog or I-love-hotdog is wrong right?

Ive read around some say do this www.food.com/food/3123/hotdog or www.food.com/food/hotdog3123 then parse it

Has anyone got the right way to do it? or better yet the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching with "hotdog" or "I-love-hotdog" is rather OK. You can store additional field in DB table named "url" (for example). Note that "url" field MUST be uinique. Then in `application/bootstrap.php` create correct routes which will serve your requests taking `url` part of product and then search it in DB with controller.

Making `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202703` automaticaly redirect to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202703/seo-urls-with-kohana-strategy` is possible with Kohana's `$this->request->redirect()` (`Request::redirect()`) method. In controller you get the ID of item (in our example `10202703`) then find corresponding URL (`seo-urls-with-kohana-strategy`) of item and redirect to `$this->request->uri().'/'.$item_url` by `$this->request->redirect('/'.$this->request->uri().'/'.$item_url)`

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but wont searching the url field mean i wont take advantage of the index on ID?

Comment: ok of if I my links are www.food.com/333/hotdog-from-heaven and m controller uses 333 to find article thats considered SEO friendly?

Comment: OH, I see stack overflow if we put this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202703/ without slug then its ok it works, but it reloads with the slug, any idea how to do this on kohana?

Comment: `www.food.com/333/hotdog-from-heaven` is good. Or you can simply use GET query: `www.food.com/hotdog-from-heaven?id=333`

Comment: `it reloads with the slug` - can't understand question

Comment: I mean if I put http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202703/ then it will reload as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202703/seo-urls-with-kohana-strategy with the extra part at the end seo-urls-with-kohana-strategy